# How do I get the Slurm job id using the Perl API?

Tags: perl, slurm

In [Slurm](http://slurm.schedmd.com/), a job submitted with the `sbatch` command-line tool returns its job id. How do I get the job id using the [Perl API](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man3/Slurm.3pm.html)?

Comment: Hello. I'm afraid your question doesn't really have enough detail for a good answer. It's likely to attract downvotes as a result. Usually on StackOverflow some code is expected, as that's the focus of this site.

Answer (score 2):

If you submit a job like this:

```
$resp = $slurm->submit_batch_job($job_desc_msg);
```

try and look into `$resp` for a new field named `job_id`

```
$jobid = $resp->{job_id} if $resp;
```

that would be set if the command was successful.

Comment: What will be the structure of $job_desc_msg. Assume I am having a batch script to be executed by the SLURM and the batch script name is somescript.cp . How the batch script will be submitted